# How to use Kivy SDK to compile the project?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to compile my first Kivy project, which is the "pong" example provided on Kivy's website. I checked the code, everything works fine when I type in "kivy main.py" in the terminal. Then I followed the instructions here (https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-osx.html) to create a package for OSX (I'm assuming this is what I need next ) until this step:

> "Now all you need to do is to include your compiled app in the Kivy.app by running the following command:

```
osx> ./package-app.sh /path/to/your/<app_folder_name>/"
```

But here is the problem: there is no "package-app.sh" in the directory!
And I don't have a "compiled app", isn't that what I'm trying to get, to compile my app?

If you have used Kivy before this must be a very simple problem. I'm just so new to it it's not making any sense. Please help. Also, unless there is a good reason to use buildozer instead, I'd prefer the idk. But please do explain.

Thank you!